# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE laravel

Tags: php, laravel

У меня проблема с crud а именно update laravel. Отправляю запрос выдает ошибку

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.
>   Мой запрос blade

```
<form action="{{ route('profile.update', Auth::user()->id) }}" method="POST" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@method('PUT')
@csrf
{{-- <div><label for="">Почта</label></div> --}}
<span class="badge badge-success">Почта</span>
<div class="form-profile">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}">  
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button> 
</div>
```

Мой контроллер:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    DB::table('users')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->update([
        'email' => $request->email,
    ]);
    return redirect(route('user.user_profile.index', $id));
}
```

Маршрут:

```
Route::prefix('user')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('/profile', 'ProfileController');
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В отрисованном браузером DOM нет этих строк `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />`. Перепроверьте наличие `@method('PUT')` в вашем шаблоне. Ну и наличие закрывающего тега `</form>`

Comment: Возможно кэш шаблонов старый, подчистите: `storage/framework/views`. Либо вы предоставили неактуальные данные в вопросе.

Comment: Да и токена `@csrf` в DOM не видно. Ну и `enctype="multipart/form-data"` также в DOM отсутствует.

Comment: @РустамГимранов все спасибо!

Comment: И в чем решение ошибки заключалось?

Comment: @РустамГимранов нужно поменять местами csrf и method('PUT')

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была просто нужно была поменять местам

```
<form action="{{ route('profile.update', Auth::user()->id) }}" method="POST" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <div class="form-profile">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}">  
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button> 
   </div>
</form>
```